# Error in plotting scatter plot using GGally package

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I want to plot a scatterplot using GGally package. 
My data frame contains these numbers

```
152861.1277 0.751206523 2013    1.35E+239   6.29E+03    2.00E-01    24.75857978 0.001103093 8.35E+04
127194.554  0.691661805 694 2.84E+238   6.29E+03    2.00E-01    14.97627887 0.000379999 5.26E+03
6.06E+04    5.34E-01    3.28E+02    5.16E+237   6.28E+03    2.00E-01    18.07714174 1.80E-04    1.01E+03
40410.08303 0.479646356 271 3.32E+237   6.28E+03    2.00E-01    32.25630782 0.000148763 1.89E+03
```

I wrote these code:

```
library(GGally)

    ggscatmat(df,alpha=0.8)  + 
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  labs(title = "Scatterplot")
```

but I faced this error

```
Error in if ((w[1] * sm + w[2] * cm + w[3] * dm + w[4]) < best$score) break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: When asking for help you should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we test the code and determine the cause of the error.

Comment: @MrFlick Your right, But I didn't know why is this problem happens. I have plot this kind of code before and I didn't have problem. I have a large data frame so I just passed 3 rows of that here and I still have this problem for plotting these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug in the `labeling` package.
The issue and work arounds are reported in [ggplot2 github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1957).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ggplot2 and the same error pops up when trying to show very large number on "y-axis". My issue resolved by using

```
+scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
```

Probably try this one?